# Is there an "easy" way to find the minimum of $\frac{f(x) + g(y)}{x+y}$ where $f$ and $g$ are convex but $\frac{f(x) + g(y)}{x+y}$ is not?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Suppose I have a problem of the form
$$min_{x \geq \epsilon, y \geq 0} \frac{f(x) + g(y)}{x+y}$$
subject to some (convex) inequality constraints and some affine equality constraints, and where $f$ and $g$ are known to be convex, and $\epsilon > 0$ is some known constant. We can also assume that the feasible set is compact (in addition to being convex).

The main challenge here is when $\frac{f(x) + g(y)}{x+y}$ is not convex (otherwise it is just a convex problem), and also we don't have an easy escape like $f$ and $g$ are log convex, for example.

In my specific situation, I also know that $f,g$ are of the form

$$f(x) = \int_0^x h_f(u)\ du~,$$
and
$$g(x) = \int_0^x h_g(u)\ du~,$$
for some (known) nondecreasing and integrable (but not necessarily continuous) functions $h_f: [0,B_f] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $h_g: [0,B_g] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ for some real numbers $0 < B_f, B_g < \infty$.

Are there any easy ways to tackle this sort of problem? I am hoping to find ways that would be computationally not much more difficult than convex optimization, but I am not sure if this is possible... it seems like even the simpler problem of minimizing $f(x)/x$ is (surprisingly) difficult...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it by bisection, i.e. use bisection to find smallest possible $t$ such that $f(x) + g(x) \leq t(x+y)$. For fixed $t$ this is a convex set, and you would thus use your convex programming machinery if available for your particular functions.